# Performing the same operation on many attributes of a python object

Tags: python

I have the following Python object:

```
class car(object):

    def __init__(self, name, cost, type, speed):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost
        self.type = type
        self.speed = speed

    def get_name(self): return self.name
    def get_cost(self): return self.cost
    def get_type(self): return self.type
    def get_speed(self): return self.speed
```

I then want to perform the same operation to some parameters of the object. I want to add 1 to each specified attribute.

One way of doing this is obviously:

```
obj = car('volvo', 100, 0, 5)
obj.cost = obj.cost + 1
obj.type = obj.type + 1
obj.speed = obj.speed + 1
```

But this wastes several lines of code. Is there a way to do something like:

```
attributesToModify = ['cost', 'type', 'speed']
for e in attributesToModify:
    obj.e = obj.e + 1
```

Comment: Take a look at [Getting dynamic attribute in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595690/getting-dynamic-attribute-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) and [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
attributesToModify = ['cost', 'type', 'speed']
for e in attributesToModify:
    setattr(obj, e, getattr(obj, e) + 1)
```

Comment: Not quite: you need to use `getattr` instead of `obj.e`.

Comment: I caught that looking over my code and I was *just* editing my code when you posted. :P

Answer (score 3):

You could just add a method to your class:

```
 def inc(self, i):
    self.cost += i
    self.type += i
    self.speed += i
```

Then pass in the increment:

```
obj.inc(1)
```

Comment: This wouldn't be best for my actual use case. I have 5 attributes and I want to vary them by +/- the attributes value by 20% and only vary each attribute one at a time.

Comment: @Apollo, that can all be done in the method. Once you know what you want to do you can take other args.