# Django: how to get field by field name from Model instance dynamically?

Tags: django

I have a model instance and a variable that contains name of the field that I have to print:

```
field_name = "is_staff"
user = User.objects.get(pk=0)
```

How do I get the value of that field by field_name? I can't just say `user.is_staff`, cause I can't hard-code that the field is called `is_staff`.

Importantly, I need to assign a value to the field, obtained this way: `user.is_staff = True`.

Comment: Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr). What does this have to do with Django? Also, consider carefully why you're doing this. "Variable variables" are nearly always a code smell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting dynamic attribute in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595690/getting-dynamic-attribute-in-python)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use can use `getattr'. It works like this

```
field_name = "is_staff"
user = User.objects.get(pk=0)
field_name_val = getattr(user, field_name)
```

Comment: Can I assign a value to this field, e.g. `getattr(user, field_name) = False`?

Comment: @Bob To assign use `setattr(user, field_name, False)`